# Remove WPF Validation adornment from Label

Tags: wpf, validation, adornment

I am using databinding and IDataErrorInfo style validation in a form. This form includes a Label control for which I don't want to show the red adornment when validation fails. Can anyone recommend a way to remove this adornment from Label controls?

Comment: Can you post the xaml for the relevant part of your form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get rid of the default validation error template by assigning an empty `ControlTemplate` to the attached property [`Validation.ErrorTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate.aspx).

```
<Label Content="{Binding ...}">
  <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate />
  </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</Label>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect and simple. Thanks Oskar.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable validation for a Binding by disabling the relevant Validation mode.
These can be one or all of `ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors`, `ValidatesOnDataErrors` and `ValidatesOnExceptions`.

```
<Label Content="{Binding YOUR_BINDING_PROPERTY, 
                 ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=False,
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=False,
                 ValidatesOnExceptions=False}" />
```

Comment: I had a similar problem; your answer fixed it.